# Applying overlay to haskellPackages

Tags: haskell, nix

I've seen that with overlay we can easily customize nixpkgs. A quick google search I get pretty nice result like this, take from  :

```
# Creating an overlay
let overlay1 = self: super:
{
   google-chrome = super.google-chrome.override {
   commandLineArgs =
     "--proxy-server='https=127.0.0.1:3128;http=127.0.0.1:3128'";
   };
};

# Actually using it
import <nixpkgs> { overlays = [ overlay1 ]; }
```

But I'm actually at lost on how to modify existing haskell packages using overlay. I want to disable testing on `hasktags` with overlay. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more digging, this works for me:

```
self: super: {
  haskellPackages = super.haskellPackages.override {
    overrides = haskellSelf: haskellSuper: {
      hasktags = self.haskell.lib.dontCheck haskellSuper.hasktags;
    };
  };
}
```

and place it on `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays.nix` or `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/` directory.

The example above is when you want to disable testing on `hasktags`. The idea applies for every other packages.

Comment: If you want use overlays on `haskellPackages` - adding overrides in stages - you can use `haskellPackages.extend`, although at the time of writing, it is [incompatible](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/26561) with `haskellPackages.override`.

Comment: @RobertHensing Hi, thanks for the comment! I can't find any documentation about `.extend` can you tell me what it is?

Comment: Sadly, it's not in the manual. Here's a usage example though: https://gist.github.com/srhb/9995a60cbec68fab2b87b078e26c5753#file-tensorflow-proto-shell-nix-L8-L11